# ArcGIS / Esri Custom Theme not showing in appbuilder

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I've followed the instructions here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/create-a-theme.htm

Created the correct scaffold, placed in `stemapp/themes` but I just can't get it to show up. Also, when I edit the DemoTheme, my changes aren't displaying. I've cleared my cache, using incognito but it's just not working. I've also used the yo generator to scaffold the theme, but no dice. https://github.com/Esri/generator-esri-appbuilder-js

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. If using Demo Theme, by default, it is disabled. To enable it, open the .repoignore file in client\stemapp\themes, remove DemoTheme from the file, and restart the node server.
2. During development, use "http://your host/webappbuilder/?id=stemapp" to access your theme directly.

If it doesn't appear here, you are not following the instructions correctly. Make sure all your theme names are well placed. There must be instances where you still have names from your copied theme(e.g DemoTheme), replace all of them with your theme's name. It should appear.

Comment: Thanks, this was almost a year ago and I'm not likely to try again. Hopefully the instructions have become better since then!

Comment: I understand that your question is too old, but this suggestion may come in handy to newbies looking for resolution to similar issue faced by them. I was recently working on custom theme and came across your question, hence i answered.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the ArcGISWebAppBuider service worked for me